# Am I understanding Hilbert's Basis Theorem correctly?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hilbert's Basis Theorem states that any ideal in $F[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ has a finite basis.

Let $I\subset F[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ be an ideal generated by $\langle f_1(X),f_2(X),\dots\rangle$.

Going by my understanding, $I$ can be generated by $\leq n$ elements: $I=\langle g_1(X),g_2(X)\dots,g_n(X)\rangle$, **where each $g_i(X)\in I$ is the polynomial of lowest degree in $x_i$**. Naturally, if $g_m(X)=g_n(X)$ for some $m,n\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, the number of elements in the basis of $I$ will be less than $n$.

Is this intuition correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I seem to recall thinking the same, but being told that this was not the case (I forget if we needed $2$ or $3$ variables to get a counterexample).

Comment: Never mistake intuition with a wild guess.

Answer (score 4):

This is not correct. The ideal $(x^n, yx^{n-1}, y^2x^{n-2},\ldots,y^n)$ is not generated by less than $n$ elements.